# "404 - File or directory not found" error when logging in to DocuSign API

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using the code listed below for a c# visual studio project to interface with the DocuSign API.  As soon as the code gets to

```
LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();
```

I am getting error message:

> 404 - File or directory not found.
>   The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Does anyone know why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using DocuSign.eSign.Api;
using DocuSign.eSign.Model;
using DocuSign.eSign.Client;

namespace CoreRecipes
{
    class Program
    {
        private string INTEGRATOR_KEY = "[key]";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program recipes = new Program();
            recipes.listDocumentsAndDownloadTest();
            Console.Read();
        }
        public void listDocumentsAndDownloadTest()
        {
            string username = "[username]";
            string password = "[password]";
            string envelopeId = "envelopid";
            //configureApiClient("www.docusign.net/restapi");
            //http"s://demo.docusign.net/restapi"
            configureApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restpi");
            string accountId = loginApi(username, password);
            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
            EnvelopeDocumentsResult docsList = envelopesApi.ListDocuments(accountId, envelopeId);
            Console.WriteLine("EnvelopeDocumentsResult:\n{0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(docsList));
            int docCount = docsList.EnvelopeDocuments.Count;
            string filePath = null;
            FileStream fs = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < docCount; i++)
            {                
                MemoryStream docStream = (MemoryStream)envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, docsList.EnvelopeDocuments[i].DocumentId);
                filePath = Path.GetTempPath() + Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".pdf";
                fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                docStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                docStream.CopyTo(fs);
                fs.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Envelope Document {0} has been downloaded to:  {1}", i, filePath);
            }
        }
        public void configureApiClient(string basePath)
        {
            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
            Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;
        }
        public string loginApi(string usr, string pwd)
        {
            ApiClient apiClient = Configuration.Default.ApiClient;
            string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + usr + "\", \"Password\":\"" + pwd + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + INTEGRATOR_KEY + "\"}";
            Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
            string accountId = null;
            AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
            LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();
            foreach (LoginAccount loginAcct in loginInfo.LoginAccounts)
            {
                if (loginAcct.IsDefault == "true")
                {
                    accountId = loginAcct.AccountId;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (accountId == null)
            { 
                accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;
            }
            return accountId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am going to speculate that you meant to use `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi`

Comment: @mjwills, No, Op is most probably using C# API

Comment: It was a typo issue, thanks for catching this

Comment: Please add correct URI in the answer so that others can get benefit from this post.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with this list:

```
configureApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restpi")
```

There is a typo in it - as identified by going to https://demo.docusign.net/restpi and seeing that it returned a 404.

I suggest changing it to:

```
configureApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi")
```